# How can I implement the mouse pressed method into a animated game without creating another class?

Tags: java, mouseevent

This is the code for the flappy bird. it is all in one class, and I don't know if that's a problem or not, and how would I fix it? The mouse listener implementation might be wrong.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Flappy extends JFrame implements MouseListener {


public static Image loadImage (String name)  //Loads image from file
{
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try
    {
        img = ImageIO.read (new File (name));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
    return img;
}

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Image back,ground, bird, upper, lower;
 int y=200,vy=1;//speed and acceleration respectively
 int xPipe1=600,yPipe1=(int)(Math.random()*300)+250;//random numbers for pipes
int xPipe2=900,yPipe2=(int)(Math.random()*300)+250;
 int xPipe3=1200,yPipe3=(int)(Math.random()*300)+250;
public Flappy ()
{
    this.setTitle("Flappy Bird");//the jframe
    this.setSize(400,700);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
//Here is the problem, adding the mouse listener to the jframe
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new Flappy();



}
public void paint (Graphics g) {

    //loop that draws the images
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon("image/background.jpg");
    back=i.getImage();
    ImageIcon j=new ImageIcon("image/ground.png");
    ground=j.getImage();
    ImageIcon k=new ImageIcon("image/wingup.png");
    bird=k.getImage();
    ImageIcon l=new ImageIcon("image/pipe-up.png");
    lower=l.getImage();
    ImageIcon m=new ImageIcon("image/pipe-down.png");
    upper=m.getImage();


    for (int backPos=0;backPos>-1200;backPos--)
    {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(30);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        g2d.drawImage(back, backPos, 0, null);



        g2d.drawImage(lower,xPipe1,yPipe1,null);
        g2d.drawImage(upper,xPipe1,yPipe1-600,null);
        xPipe1-=5;
        g2d.drawImage(lower,xPipe2,yPipe2,null);
        g2d.drawImage(upper,xPipe2,yPipe2-600,null);
        xPipe2-=5;
        g2d.drawImage(lower,xPipe3,yPipe3,null);
        g2d.drawImage(upper,xPipe3,yPipe3-600,null);
        xPipe3-=5;
        if(xPipe1==-80)
        {
            xPipe1=800;
            yPipe1=(int)(Math.random()*300)+250;
        }


        if(xPipe2==-80)
        {
            xPipe2=800;
            yPipe2=(int)(Math.random()*300)+250;
        }
        if(xPipe3==-80)
        {
            xPipe3=800;
            yPipe3=(int)(Math.random()*300)+250;
        }

        g2d.drawImage(ground,0,129,null);



        g2d.drawImage(bird,150,y,null);
        if (y<590)
        {
        vy+=3;
        y+=vy;
        }
        else
        {
            y=590;

        }
        if(backPos==-1100)
        {
            backPos=0;
        }
    }

}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    vy=-100;//The bird is supposed to flap here, but there is no input
}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are the listener methods not called?

Comment: Yes. Problem is i can't.

Comment: What do you mean by "you cannot"? Are any of the listener methods called when mouse actions happen?

Comment: They are called. But the problem is either mouselistener isn't responding, or i implemented it incorrectly(which is most likely the case).

Comment: maybe you need to call "repaint()" to get the screen to refresh?

Comment: nope. it paints, just doesn't do what should happen when the mouse is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot: instead of implementing a `mouseListener` to your whole class, just, when defining things in your constructor, create a new `mouseListener` object there. For example:

```
public flappy(){
    //define stuff here
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
        public void onClick(MouseEvent e){
            //action goes here
        }
        //you will get an error to include other voids. Just click on "add unimplemented methods".
    });
}
```

Comment: Make a class extending JPanel, add the mouse listener to the JPanel, and add the JPanel into a frame.

Comment: Where would I draw the JPanel? Is it transparent?

Comment: On your JFrame, in the constructor, try addding "this.add(new PanelClass());" or whatever your panel is called. On your JPanel call "addMouseListener(new MouseListener())" on the JPanel constructor. Call your on click action inside of the little void inside of your constructor.

Comment: What to do mean "is it transparent?"

Comment: so it doesn't obstruct the images/jframe

Comment: no what I'm saying is that you should move all of your drawing inside of the JPanel because normally that's what people do when making games and its more productive and stuff

Comment: ah i see. I'll give it a shot. Never thought about doing that.